# Problems with making a night sky in a 2D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

i am making a 2D war game which has time. I made a night and day cycle for my game with a timer, the code is down below. What i did was change the opacity of a sprite rendered square to go down and go up according if the night was approaching or it was the start of the day etc. etc. wasNight boolean is to check if it was dark before so it wouldn't just blink to a brightness once its 1AM again. The problem: This code works, but the NightDayCycle() is written horribly and if i wanted to implement something new it would be VERY annoying and hard. I was wondering if there was a better way to write this piece of code:

```
void Update()
{
      NightDayCycle();
      if (TimeStopped == true)
      {

      }
      else if (TimeStopped == false)
      {
          TimerMethod();
      }
        
}
public void TimerMethod()
    {
        Timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (Timer <= 0)
        {
            Hour++;
            if (Hour >= 25)
            {
                Day++;
                Hour = 1;
                if (Day >= 30)
                {
                    Month++;
                    Day = 1;
                    if (Month >= 12)
                    {
                        Year++;
                        Month = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            Timer = hourToRealTime;
        }
    }
public void NightDayCycle()
    {
        if (wasNight == false)
        {
            if (Hour == 1)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 2)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.96f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 3)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.92f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 4)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.88f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 5)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.84f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 6)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.80f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 7)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.76f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 8)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.72f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 9)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.68f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 10)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.64f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 11)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.60f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 12)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.56f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 13)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.52f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 14)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.48f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 15)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.44f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 16)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.40f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 17)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.36f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 18)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.32f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 19)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.28f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 20)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.24f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 21)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.20f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 22)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.16f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 23)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.12f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 24)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.04f);
                wasNight = true;
                Hour = 1; //Goes straight to the code below
            }
        }
        else if (wasNight == true)
        {
            if (Hour == 1)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.04f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 2)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.08f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 3)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.12f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 4)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.16f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 5)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.20f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 6)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.24f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 7)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.28f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 8)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.32f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 9)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.36f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 10)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.40f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 11)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.44f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 12)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.48f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 13)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.52f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 14)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.56f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 15)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.60f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 16)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.64f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 17)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.68f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 18)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.72f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 19)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.76f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 20)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.80f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 21)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.84f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 22)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.88f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 23)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.92f);
            }
            else if (Hour == 24)
            {
                NightDay.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
                wasNight = false;
                Hour = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: You can use [Color.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html) to change the color and use a normalized value (as t for the lerp) based on your Hour variable.  You can use `1-t` and `t` to handle both day/night states for the color lerp.

Comment: @hijinxbassist i dont really understand how should i do it with Color.Lerp, is it possible to somehow do it with foreach?

Comment: foreach is not really the right tool for this job, but it is possible to do with foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor this code to use [Color.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html), and as a result reduce the amount of code needed.

1. In `NightDayCycle()` get a normalized value for the lerp.

   ```
   var t = (Hour - 1) / 24f;
   ```
2. Invert the `t` variable based on the `wasNight` variable.  This is the same as swapping the color arguments in the lerp function.

   ```
   t = wasNight ? t : 1 - t;
   ```
3. Use `t` in the `Color.Lerp` function to ease between the 2 colors.

   ```
   NightDay.color = Color.Lerp(whiteTransparent, whiteOpaque, t);
   ```
4. Set the `wasNight` variable from within the `TimerMethod()`, not in the `NightDayCycle()` method.

   ```
   if (Hour >= 25)
   {
       wasNight = !wasNight; // <- flips the value
       ...
   }
   ```
5. Rejoice, there are no more `if/else` statements in your `NightDayCycle()` method.